# Can Admin panel and user panel in one solution - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, architecture, software-design

i am developing an online election web page using `ASP.NET`.I have completed the user panel.Now i am trying to develop the Admin panel for my web site.

[image]

I have created the both admin panel and user panel as `Web Application` and included both them in one `Solution` explorer.
Is this the standard of using an admin panel in a website ? If not can you suggest me how to do this.

Thanx in advance !

Comment: I see no problem with that, you may even end up using the same views for both roles (Admin and User) and change the layout based on the currently logged-in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate, protected folder for your admin forms. Then use membership to create users and roles: for example, you could have admin and editor roles limiting administration abilities, etc.

https://www.asp.net/identity

Looking at your solution, I would make the following suggestions: it is not "necessary" to have your admin logic in a separate project but that might be dictated by your support/maintenance priorities later on. I would not use the word "panel" as this suggests an ASP.NET control.